# Text values for list-style-type CSS property, how?

Tags: jquery, html, css, html-lists, listitem

I'd like to customize the way items of unordered lists are presented.

I know I can use `list-style-type` to change between `none`, `disc`, `circle`, `square` and other more or less supported values. I also know it is possible to change the default appearance of list markers specifying an image to `list-style-image` property.

The problem is that I want to replace the bullet with `large right arrow` (►, `&#9658;`) HTML special character instead of use a combination of `list-style-image` and a triangular image.

Is it possible? Btw, if this matters jQuery is already loaded on the page so it wouldn't be a problem to use it if this can help.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

To my knowledge, it's not possible to do that using the [list-style-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/css/list-style-type) property.

However, if your browser supports the [:before](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/:before) CSS selector, you can use it to insert the bullet entities before the list items. You only need to convert the entity code to hexadecimal:

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

li:before {
    content: "\25ba\00a0";
}
```

You can find a jsFiddle demonstrating this [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Vj8dd/1/).

Comment: I was working on something similar myself. I won't bother to post an answer now, here's where I got to: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/ZTKuS/

Comment: +1 beat me to it, a handy conversion calculator for those entities can be found [here](http://www.evotech.net/articles/testjsentities.html)

Comment: +1 this won't work in [IE6 and 7](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html) but if that's not a necessity, it's a very nice workaround.

Answer (score 6):

@Frederic shows an interesting workaround that I would go with, unless you have to support IE6 and 7 - in that case,  you'd have to work around with a normal HTML element that contains the character, and that you style to put it into the right place.

Something like

```
ul { list-style-type: none } /* Adjust margin and padding as you see fit */
ul li div.bullet { float: left; width: 30px; margin-right: 12px }

<li>
 <div class="bullet">&#9658;</div>
 List item 1
</li>
```

Answer (score 4):

If you use the [:before](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/%3abefore) method to get your list-style think about adding a padding to the list and a negative margin to the list-element to get the same space at line-break:

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0 0 0 24px
}
ul > li:before {
    content: '\25BA';
    float: left;
    margin-left: -24px
}
```

Just use the example postet from thirtydot to try in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/ZTKuS/)

Answer (score 3):

It took a while, but `list-style-type: <string>` [has arrived in Chromium](https://blog.chromium.org/2019/10/chrome-79-beta-virtual-reality-comes-to.html).

> Allows a stylesheet to use an arbitrary character for the list style
>   marker.